# Want Android Image Processing without OpenCV or any other liberary which use NDK

Tags: android, image-processing

I am developing and android application which needs image processing task on real time basis 
i am using OpenCV tutorial 0 for camera setup and using the same class i have done coding till receiving real time images, 
Now i want to detect a logo and detect smile 
most of the searches i have made on internet are based on OpenCV or used such libraries which turns the application so heavily or use NDK which i found very difficult to integrate. 
I want the simple java implementation for detecting features which take very few resources as i have to do many other tasks simultaneously 
Can any one reffer me some book or website or any other link or any piece of code for image matching and smile detections technich, please help i am really stucked i have tried the following code but not much helpful as is is pixel to pixel matching

```
private boolean  bit_match(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
{  
    boolean first_x = false;
    int x1 = -2, x2 = -2,y1,y2;
    int minx1=-1,maxx2=-1,miny1=-1,maxy2=-1;
    int w = bmp1.getWidth();
    int h = bmp1.getHeight();

    int[]  pixels1 = new int[w * h];
    int[] pixels2 = new int[w * h];

      total_rounds=0;
      match_count=0;


    //long start = new Date().getTime();
     bmp1.getPixels( pixels1, 0,w, 0, 0, w, h );
     bmp2.getPixels( pixels2, 0,w, 0, 0, w, h );


     for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) 
            {
                    if (pixels2[i + j * w] != pixels1[i + j * w]) 
                    {
                        if(!first_x){ minx1=i; miny1=j; maxx2=i; maxy2=j; first_x = true; }
                        if(minx1>i) minx1 = i;
                        if(miny1>j) miny1 = j;
                        if(maxx2<i) maxx2 = i;
                        if(maxy2<j) maxy2 = j;
                        // System.out.println(i +"x"+ j);
                    }else{ match_count++;}

                    total_rounds++;
            }
     }
     if(minx1==maxx2 && maxy2==miny1)
     { 
         //System.out.println("Un singur pixel modificat");
         //Toast.makeText(this,"Un Modified", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         return true;
     }
     else{
        // System.out.println("Modified part (rectangle): "+minx1+","+miny1+"<->"+maxx2+","+maxy2);
         //Toast.makeText(this,"Modified part (rectangle): "+minx1+","+miny1+"<->"+maxx2+","+maxy2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     return false;  
     }

}
```

accuracy is not important much i can compromise with the accuracy for now as i just need the idea

Comment: Image processing is too slow if you do it in Java. That is basically why people use the NDK.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, actually as being high level language developer and by using visual studio all the time i really has no idea about make file and how to configure or use NDK, that's why i am afraid to use it

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use NDK if you want to do image processing with OpenCV for Android. Please check [this description](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#java). I know it is not simple but on your development level you only have to write pure Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of image processing via the NDK https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoProcessing
You could also use OpenGL for image processing if you didn't want to mess with the NDK although for what you want to do I would recommend the NDK

Comment: Thanks but i really dont want to mess with NDK as i really have no idea about how to use it, i have idea about OpenGL that's why i have asked if any implementation example found so that i can use it